# counting join subquery by mainquery

Tags: mysql

Why is the result of countTypes NULL ?
I need the counts based of the main query (a.id's).
I get the counts only if i put the same on a WHERE clause but i need a solution without double WHERE clause.

Thanks in advance.

```
items

id  type
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    3

SELECT a.id, countTypes FROM items AS a
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(CONCAT('countType', type), count)) as countTypes
            FROM (SELECT id, type, count(id) AS count FROM items GROUP BY type) AS b
           ) AS c ON c.id = a.id
WHERE a.id >= '100' AND a.id <= '200'
```

Comment: Trying adding `id` to your GROUP BY statement.

Comment: does not work too

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain your requirement more completely. With respect, it's hard to guess what you want by looking at the query in your question/

Answer (score 0):

Your innermost subquery query is this.

```
        SELECT id, type, count(id) AS count FROM items GROUP BY type
```

Here you have run afoul of [MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Your query actually means

```
        SELECT ANY_VALUE(id), type, count(id) AS count FROM items GROUP BY type
```

Where [`ANY_VALUE()` formally means MySQL may return an unpredictable value for that column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value). *Unpredictable* can be confusing. That's why MySQL's extension is notorious.

You need

```
        SELECT id, type, count(id) AS count FROM items GROUP BY id, type
```

for this subquery to be predictable. But I guess you want the count of types in items, so what you want is this.

```
        SELECT type, count(*) AS count FROM items GROUP BY type
```

Your outer query says

```
SELECT a.id 
  FROM items 
  JOIN (subquery) c ON c.id = a.id
 WHERE a.id >= '100'
  AND a.id <= '200'
```

Your outer query returns no items from your subuery so it's not clear what result you need. Inner JOIN operations can serve to filter a resultset. But because of your `ANY_VALUE(id)` situation, your filter is unpredicatable.

Comment: Can you please explain me what was he trying to do? I do not understand his question.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
i only need the type counts based on the mainquery filtered result.
e.g. [{"countType1": 2}, {"countType2": 2}, {"countType3": 1}]

Comment: @O. Jones
I understood that correctly, it is not possible that way ?

Comment: oops i had forgotten countTypes in the mainquery, but i added it now